# Microsoft login isn't returning refresh token

Tags: javascript, outlook, calendar, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to create an integration between my application and Microsoft calendar,

I have a page which allows the user to connect his account with my App
using the following code

```
    const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
            clientId: '<client-id>',
        },
    });
    msalInstance.loginRedirect({
        scopes: ['user.read', 'calendars.readwrite', 'offline_access', 'openid'],
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    });
```

The login is working and returns token and I can create an event easily
But the token expires after 1 hour, and the response doesn't contain a refresh token
Is there a way to generate a refresh token, or create a token that will stay active for a longer period.
Because I want the user to login once and just create an integration between my app and azure.
Same as the outlook calendar for slack.
my azure application has the needed API permissions
`openid offline_access` am I missing something?

Comment: from the name of things, it looks like you're using the microsoft authentication library, which abstracts away the refresh token and doesn't make it visible to your own code. if you need to handle session refresh in your app, or do things without the user being present, I'd suggest you handle the openid yourself (or use another library which doesn't hide the parts you need)

Comment: Yes I am using it, I'll try handling it myself and see.

Answer (score 0):

as https://stackoverflow.com/users/519348/tzhx mentioned, it was the MSAL JS library that caused the issue

I handled the login manually and I was able to see the refresh token.

Thanks.